# Is it possible to reset the blockchain with a new genesis block for efficiency?

Tags: ringct, privacy, scalability, pruning, genesisblock

I am researching state prunning, and I saw [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/what-kind-of-pruning-techniques-does-aeon-use?rq=1) that AEON state prunning does helps a bit, with some issues though because of historical reasons (details in the link).

Would it be possible to reset the blockchain history and just keep the "account balances" in a new genesis?
Would we lose any properties of Monero by doing this?

For the sake of this question, let us assume that the history is of no value to us (although I understand that the opposite case could be made).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Monero, it is impossible to distinguish between spent and unspent outputs. Therefore no one could create a new blockchain with just the unspent outputs from the current blockchain, because the unspent outputs are unknowable.