# Is there a monero pruned blockchain mode like how bitcoin core has a pruned blockchain?

Tags: blockchain-size, pruning

Monero's blockchain is almost 50GB as of March 2018 and my laptop doesn't have that much space to spare anymore. Is there a pruned version of the monero blockchain?

Comment: No. The closest is AEON's pruning described in [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/what-kind-of-pruning-techniques-does-aeon-use).

Comment: @ClementJ. you should post your comment as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just came across this very old question and saw that it hasn't been updated, yet. Yes, you can now prune the blockchain.

Look up `monerod` parameter `--prune-blockchan` here: https://monerodocs.org/interacting/monerod-reference/

There's also the `monero-blockchain-prune` command line tool.

Comment: MoneroDocs.org is no longer available; please use https://getmonero.dev/docs/interacting/monerod-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. Pruning is currently being implemented though, with chances to be in the next hard fork.